# Regex question - line breaks (or not)

Tags: regex

here's my string:

```
</HEAD>
<BODY>


<html>
<head>
```

i need to detect the line-breaks so i used `[\r\n]+`
but the problem is, i need it to be optional - like the filter rule should also work if there are no line breaks at all (between rbody + html)  .. how would i do that?

thx

Comment: What do you need in result? May be `[\r\n]*` should be used instead?

Comment: I agree with Ivan on detecting "0 or more" line breaks, however, I think that parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea. An HTML parser is a little more complex but will help you avoid a lot of headache

Comment: you're right but i'm in need of regex because it is for spam filtering :(

Comment: `[\r\n]+` **is** optional.  If something isn't working, consider posting your regex and a test string that fails.

Comment: I believe the quantifiers are: ? means 0 or 1, * means 0 or more, and + means 1 or more.  So, + would not make it optional.

Comment: People, post your answers as answers and get reputation points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ivan and qid have it right.
`[\r\n]*` will match any linebreak characters in any amount, including 0. Using `+` meant 1 or more, thus the problem you ran into.

Answer (score -1):

try using `[\r\n]{0,}`

/Klaus

Comment: `{0,*}` should either be `{0,}` or `*`.